# How to write a vector function to apply operation f(x,y)?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, vectorization, scalar

> scalar_function can only handle scalar input, we could use the function np.vectorize() turn it into a vectorized function. Note that the input argument of np.vectorize() should be a scalar function, and the output of np.vectorize() is a new function that can handle vector input.
>
> Please write a vector function vector_function, which will apply the operation  (,)  defined above element-wisely with input vectors with same dimension x and y.

So for the scalar, I got :

```
def scalar_function(x, y):
    
    if x <= y:
        return x*y
    else:
        return x/y
```

For the vector function I have :

```
def vector_function(x, y):

    vfunc = np.vectorize(scalar_function, otypes = [float])
    return vfunc
```

From here on I am stuck.

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? What did you try to solve it ? What is the function `f(x, y)` ?

Comment: To format the code, select it and type `ctrl-k`.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.[“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

based on this
`'Please write a vector function vector_function, which will apply the operation (,) defined above element-wisely with input vectors with same dimension x and y'`
here is what you are looking for:

```py
import numpy as np
def scalar_function(x, y):
    if x <= y:
        return x*y
    else:
        return x/y

vector_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function, otypes = [float])

print(vector_function(np.array([1, 2, 3, 6]), np.array([1, 3, 4, 5])))
[Output]>>> [ 1.   6.  12.   1.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
vector_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
```